# HttpWebRequest, BeginGetResponse not called until endOfStream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on a client that uses a webservice to get some events pushed its way - the webservice is designed so, that upon the client POST'ing a subscribe command, it will send back some events of interest and keep doing so as long as the client stay connected.

When POSTing the command, the service responds (immediately) with an initial answer with these headers

```
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

and then keeps the connection open until it times out (after 30s, if the client does not send some keep-alive data)

Since it is a mix of POST + having to read the response + keeping the connection open until endOFStream, it appears I have to use HttpWebRequest with BeginGetRequestStream (to POST) and BeginGetResponse to read and act on the response.

My problem is that the BeginGetResponse callback is not called until the input stream is actually closed by the server/service (after 30s), despite AllowReadStreamBuffering being set to false.

The doc have this to say on AllowReadStreamBuffering:

> The AllowReadStreamBuffering property affects when the callback from BeginGetResponse method is called. When the AllowReadStreamBuffering property is true, the callback is raised once the entire stream has been downloaded into memory. When the AllowReadStreamBuffering property is false, the callback is raised as soon as the stream is available for reading which may be before all data has arrived.

I've seen a few suggestions that no matter what AllowReadStreamBuffering is set to, HttpWebRequest will not call BeginGetResponse until it's buffer is filled up - but I have not been able to find anything on that in the docs.

Does any one have an idea on how to control this buffering behaviour or maybe suggestion to another approach I should try when dealing with this kind of webservice?

The relevant snippets of the code I currently use, look like this:

```cs
public void open()
{
    string url = "http://funplaceontheinternet/webservice";

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;         
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
}

void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("open.GetRequestStreamCallback");

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    // End the stream request operation
    Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(result);

    // Create the post data
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_xmlEncodedSubscribeCommand);

    // Add the post data to the web request
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    postStream.Close();

    // Start the web request
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(BeginGetResponseCallback), webRequest);
}

void BeginGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    if (request != null)
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("request==null :-(");
    if (response != null)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                Debug.WriteLine("BeginGetResponseCallback - received: " + line);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("BeginGetResponseCallback - reader.EndOfStream");
        }
    }
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("response==null :-(");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that the service is a web service, but not which platform.
If this is a "normal" web service, then I assume that XML is the transport format.

If so, I suspect the problem may be that this style of communication does not really lend itself to streaming. The web service infrastructure at the server end might not be creating the SOAP envelope and payload until all the data is available. If you wanted to stream like this, you might be better using some custom service at the server end, rather than a web service.

Do you know for sure that the server is really streaming the response? (e.g confirmed with something like wireshark?)

If you really want to use a web service, then I would suggest you complete the request when the first event(s) are available, and don't wait for the timeout. This will still achieve the latency reduction that I assume you are trying to get.